# Confusion between "planet" and "star" in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

It seems that the formal terms for "planet" (行星) and "star" (like the Sun) (恆星) are pronounced identically in Cantonese (both Jyutping: hang4 sing1). Given that these terms are often discussed together, and it is important that they not be confused, I was wonder how do Cantonese speakers manage to differentiate the two terms when speaking in an astronomical context.

Answer (score 4):

we may assumed the listener know what the utterance means, according to the context.

another approach is to pronounce 恆星 as 
[hang1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/hang4.Mp3)　[sing1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sing1.Mp3)

meanwhile, deliberately pronounce 行星 as [haang4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/haang4.Mp3)　[sing1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sing1.Mp3)

this one is what i learned in primary school, a long time ago.

actually, in cantonese, we pronounce 行 as [haang4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/haang4.Mp3) in 行街, 行船.